# Vim Gitgutter signs only update on focus gain

Tags: vim

I've just installed GitGutter for Vim and the `g:gitgutter_realtime` doesn't seem to be working. The signs only seems to update if I enter a new window (`Ctrl + ww`) and then focus on the original window again.

I've tried `set updatetime=250` and that doesn't appear to make a difference, if I run `:GitGutterEnable` it updates it straight away but I don't really want to run that everytime I make a change.

I currently have this in my `.vimrc`

```
let g:gitgutter_highlight_lines = 1
let g:gitgutter_realtime = 1
let g:gitgutter_eager = 1
set updatetime=250
```

What is it I'm missing?

Comment: Use the plugin's issue tracker.

Comment: Have done [here](https://github.com/airblade/vim-gitgutter/issues/298)

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question, but I have to say that, in my case, the plugin `enricobacis/vim-airline-clock` makes GitGutter real time not working.

In your case, it could be the same plugin or another using a real time feature.